# How to customize the UIPickerView or any other control in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIPickerview customisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901545/uipickerview-customisation)

How to customize the UIPickerView or any other control in iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

"UIPickerView is not customizable. At all."

[UIPickerview customisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901545/uipickerview-customisation)

Comment: as this answer is duplicating another answer from the duplicate question, may you simply delete it?